# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: react, react-hooks

Eai, comecei com reactjs a pouco tempo e decidi fazer um site com funções simples para ir aprendendo, uma dessas funções seria listar em formato de cards alguns dados que recebo do backend, mas quando tento listar os card apresenta o erro:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Dei uma olhada na net sobre esse erro mas não entendi muito bem o que podeia estar causando esse erro na minha aplicação, tenho dois componentes uma seria o componente PageInicial, que reúne todos os componentes da pagina, e o componente de Card, deixarei o código dos dois componentes a baixo, se alguém conseguir identificar onde poderia ser o erro e explicar o porque ele ocorre ajudaria muito, obrigado.

Código do componente `PageInicial`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import NavBar from "../../componentes/navbar/navbar"
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import api from '../../api'
import CardAnime from '../../componentes/card/card' 

const PageInicial = () => {

    const [animes, setAnimes] = useState([]);
    const [pageTotal, setPageTotal] = useState(0);
    const [pageAtual, setPageAtual] = useState(1);
    const [limitePorPage, setLimitePorPage] = useState(40);

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get(`/animes/listar/${pageAtual}/${limitePorPage}`).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.status) {
                console.log(response.data.erro);

            } else {
                setAnimes(response.data.animes);
                setPageTotal(response.data.pageTotal)
            }
        })
        

    }, [pageAtual]);
    return (
        <div>

            <NavBar page="home" />
            <Container fluid >
                <Row >
                    {
                        animes.map((anime)=>{
                            return (
                                <Col key={anime.id_lista} xl="3" lg="3" md="4" sm="6" >
                                    <CardAnime anime={anime} />
                                 </Col>
                             )
                        })
                    }
               
                </Row>
            </Container>

        </div>
    )
}

export default PageInicial;
```

Código do componente `Card`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter,
    Card, Badge, CardImg, CardText,
    CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle,
    Button, ListGroup, ListGroupItem
} from 'reactstrap';
import './card.css';
import YoutubeEmbed from '../video/video';
import api from "../../api"
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import semanime from "../../img/semanime.jpeg"



const CardAnime = (props) => {


    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [modalLista, setModalLista] = useState(false);
    const [generos, setGeneros] = useState([" "," "," "]);
    const [idanime, setIdanime] = useState("");
    const [lista, setLista] = useState(false)

    const { anime, noanime, openlista, login, className } = props
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
    const userid = localStorage.getItem('ID')
    const history = useHistory();

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
    const modlista = () => setModalLista(!modalLista);

    if(anime){
        setGeneros(anime.genero.split(","));
        if (generos.length > 3) {
            while (generos.length > 3) {
              generos.pop();
            }
          }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Card className="space">
                <CardImg top width="100%" className="img" src={anime.imagem} alt="Card image cap" />
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle tag="h5" >{anime.nome}</CardTitle>
                    <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
                        {
                            noanime ? "" :
                                generos.map((genero, index) => {
                                    return <Badge key={index} href="#" color="light">{genero}</Badge>
                                })
                        }
                    </CardSubtitle>
                    <CardText>
                        <ListGroup id={noanime ? "off" : "on"}>
                            <ListGroupItem> <strong>Episódios: </strong> {anime.num_ep} </ListGroupItem>
                            <ListGroupItem> <strong>Status: </strong> {anime.status} </ListGroupItem>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </CardText>
                    <Button color="success" id={noanime ? "off" : "on"} size="lg" onClick={openlista ? modlista : toggle} block>Ver</Button>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>

            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} className={className}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{anime.nome}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <YoutubeEmbed embedId={anime.trailer} />
                    <hr />
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Generos: </strong> {anime.genero} </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Episódios: </strong> {anime.num_ep} </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Status: </strong> {anime.status} </ListGroupItem>
                    </ListGroup>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter >
                    <div className="div">
                        <a id={login ? "off" : "on"} href="/login">Faça login para adicionar em listas</a>{' '}
                        <Button color="success" id={login ? "on" : "off"} onClick={() => { setIdanime(anime._id); setLista("assistir") }} >Assistir</Button>
                        <Button color="success" id={login ? "on" : "off"} onClick={() => { setIdanime(anime._id); setLista("assistidos") }} >Assistidos</Button>
                        <Button color="danger" onClick={toggle}>Fechar</Button>
                    </div>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
            <Modal isOpen={modalLista} toggle={modlista} className={className}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={modlista}>{anime.nome}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <YoutubeEmbed embedId={anime.trailer} />
                    <hr />
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Generos: </strong> {anime.genero} </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Episódios: </strong> {anime.num_ep} </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem> <strong>Status: </strong> {anime.status} </ListGroupItem>
                    </ListGroup>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter >
                    <div className="div">
                        <Button color="success" id="on" onClick={() => { setIdanime(anime._id); setLista("assistidos") }} >Assistidos</Button>
                        <Button color="danger" onClick={() => {
                        }}>Excluir</Button>
                    </div>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardAnime;
```

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que seu problema esteja nesse trecho do componente `CardAnime`.

```
if(anime){
    setGeneros(anime.genero.split(","));
    if (generos.length > 3) {
        while (generos.length > 3) {
          generos.pop();
        }
      }
}
```

Assim que você invoca o método `setGeneros` essa alteração de estado acaba gerando a re-renderização do seu componente, que por sua vez executa o `setGeneros`  novamente entrando em loop.

Sugiro que você coloque esse trecho dentro de um `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
if(anime){
    setGeneros(anime.genero.split(","));
    if (generos.length > 3) {
        while (generos.length > 3) {
          generos.pop();
        }
      }
}
}, [anime])
```

Isso ja deve bastar, para resolver o loop em seu código.

Outro ponto de atenção no seu código é este trecho:

```
if (generos.length > 3) {
        while (generos.length > 3) {
          generos.pop();
        }
      }
```

A função `pop` remove o ultimo item do seu estado de `generos`, entretanto o `pop` esta mutando o objeto diretamente, é possível que você tenha problemas no futuro por mutar um estado dessa forma.

Acredito que seu objetivo é apresentar somente os três primeiros gêneros, sendo assim sugiro que você primeiro faça a verificação necessária e caso realmente exista mais que três elementos podemos utilizar a função `slice` para gerar um novo array somente com os três primeiros valores.

```
useEffect(() => {
if(anime){
    const gen = anime.genero.split(",")
    if(generos.length > 3) setGeneros(gen.slice(0, 3));
    else setGeneros(gen)
}
}, [anime])
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações no código e resolveu até agora não apresentou mais o erro, obrigado pela dica do gêneros

Comment: Uma correção: a dependência do `useEffect` deve ser `anime` por causa do `if (anime)`. Inclusive, pelo `if` assumo que `anime` pode ser `undefined` ou `null`, nesse caso utilizar `anime.genero` na dependência causaria uma exceção.

Comment: Tem razão Rafael, não me liguei nesse detalhe, editei a resposta corrigindo a dependência do `useEffect`, muito obrigado.